# when exporting csv the columns get doubled nodejs mongo

Tags: node.js, mongodb, export-to-csv, mongoose-schema

i try to export csv with users and their subcats.date,email,category type and subcats are the columns. but when i export the csv subcats get duplicated.not other date email category and type. only subcats get repeated. there are various subcats for a user. subcats are given to the user randomly but exactly there should be 15 subcats for a user among all subcats. following is my code.

var count = 0
var csv = []

users.forEach(userele => {

```
count++

let userObj = userele.users.map((val, index) => {
    let object = {}
    object[`${val.subCats}`] = getuser(val.user)
    return object
})

for (key in userObj) {
    userObj[" " + (parseInt(key) + 5)] = userObj[key]
    delete userObj[key]
}

var expAr = {
    "Date": Date,
    "Email": userele.email,
    "Category": userele.category,
    "type": userele.type,
    ...userObj,
}
csv.push(expAr)
```

})

when i trying to export csv, the columns get repeated.i would appreciate if any one can give me a support to solve this.